# Preparing kitchen flooring for solid pine planks

Tags: flooring

For kitchen do I have to remove peel and stick vinyl  flooring to lay wide plank solid pine tongue and groove flooring? And if so can it just be nailed or must it be glued and nailed?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of flooring you're installing here? If we're talking a floating floor, you could leave it. But you might have to glue or nail solid planks. Depends a LOT on the product itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it is peel and stick squares, it should be pretty easy to remove. A floor scraper may come in handy, but a putty knife under the corner to start, if it's a small kitchen will do the job too.

Tongue and groove flooring, usually only needs nailed down, rarely glued in place, and never glue the tongues.